# CMake: find_library on runtime?

Tags: dll, path, cmake, dependencies, runtime

there are a Visual Studio solution with multiple projects and some of them them depends on the others, for example:

```
SLN
    Project1[dll]
    Project2[exe]
```

Here Project2 need Project1.lib and dll. Is it possible to find a path to Project1.lib by cmake(find_library will fail since on the time when cmake files were generated lib didn't exist) or the only way is to hardcode the path to lib?

Answer (score 0):

If they are part of the same solution, I suspect that they will be built as part of the same CMake project.

In that case, just use the target for Project1 as a dependency for Project2:

```
add_library(Project1 ...)

[...]
add_executable(Project2 ...)
target_link_libraries(Project2 Project1)
```

If, on the other hand, you want `Project1` to be built as part of `Project2` but *not* from the same CMake project, take a look at the [`ExternalProject`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/module/ExternalProject.html) module.